# AJAX Post 500 error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

im new with the whole ajax thing so maybe u guys can help me :) 
I got this code, the button and the if(post) are in the same php page and the myAjax() is in a script. but when i click on the button i got this error:

jquery.js:4 POST "site/withdraw.php" 500 (Internal Server Error)

Any help? :)

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="myAjax()">Redeem</button>

if($_POST['action'] == 'go') 
    { 
     //domethod
    }

function myAjax() {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "test";

  $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'withdraw.php',
       data:{action:'go'},
       success:function() {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "test";

       }

  });
}
```

withddraw.php

```
<?php 

if ($_POST['action'] == 'go') {
        go();
} else {
        echo "dont work";
}

function go(){
        echo "3";
        $sql = "INSERT INTO queue (test1, test2, test3) VALUES ('test', 'test', 'test')";
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: Show us your `page.php` code

Comment: Why do you ajax 'withdraw.php', but server complains about 'page.php'?

Comment: oh sorry i meant withdraw.php

Comment: Is this separate code or all in one file? It's kind of a mess.

Comment: <?php

if($_POST['action'] == 'go') 
 {
 go();
 }
 else{echo "dont work";}
 
 function go(){
  echo "3";
  $sql = "INSERT INTO queue (test1, test2, test3) VALUES ('test', 'test', 'test')";
  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "New record created successfully";
  } else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
  }
 }

 
 
?>

Comment: Is `$conn` defined anywhere in `withddraw.php`?

Comment: Yes like this  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

Answer (score 0):

A 500 error is a ***server side error*** and is completely independent of the Javascript.
- Is there a syntax error in your backend?
- Are the parameters right?
etc.

The fact that you are seeing the 500 error at least means that requests are being made to your server.

Comment: Okey, so if i remove go() in the if ($_POST['action'] == 'go') {} then i wont get an error anymore so the error is something with the go() function

Comment: Oh even when I empty the function go(), still get an error